# TiWorker.exe problems

Tags: windows, windows-10

TiWorker.exe uses up 50% of CPU and then suddenly stops when i open task manager, only reason i can see it is i use tasklist/taskkill and msi afterburner to check TiWorker. I've tried everything i could find in the internet, most wouldnt work TiWorker just keeps coming back. I also couldn't run DISM /online /cleanup-image /restorehealth command due to some error that i could search about (An error occurred while attempting to start the servicing process for the image located at C:.)

Comment: Possibly malware https://www.bing.com/search?q=tiworker.exe+malware

Comment: @Mokubai TiWorker.exe is also the process behind Windows Update on Windows 10.

Comment: @LPChip true, but it would be far less likely to "hide" itself the moment task manager is opened...

Comment: Not necessarily. TiWorker is basically a microsoft service that does many things amongst scheduled maintenance. Something that stops as soon as the system is more busy. Opening Task Manager often gives a CPU spike causing scheduled maintenance to pause. But yes, there is known malware out there that could also do this.